# Php form is not working on the specific server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the form using php script, its working fine on other server however i got the problem on the live one. below i have mention the details:

the contact form send by using ajax call & php. its working on the two servers i have checked, one of them linked below
http://www.virtualmob.co.uk/products/test_landing_pages/UrbanSpot/contact.html

however the same form when i upload it on the live server its not working  i dont know why?? :( live linked below:
http://www.urban-spot.co.uk/contact.html

the php is installed on the server, kindly let me know if any thing necessary is switched off in the server, here is the php info link:

**Here is the php code**

```
<?php


// Change this with your blog name and email address
$the_blogname   = 'MobilityApp';
$the_myemail    = 'info@urban-spot.co.uk';


if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    error_reporting(0); 
    $errorC = false;

    $the_email      = $_POST['email'];
    $the_name       = $_POST['yourname'];
    $the_message    = $_POST['message'];

    $the_phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $the_fax        = $_POST['fax'];
    $the_company    = $_POST['company'];
    $the_website    = $_POST['website'];

    # want to add aditional fields? just add them to the form in template_contact.php,
    # you dont have to edit this file

    //added fields that are not set explicit like the once above are combined and added before the actual message
    $already_used = array('email','yourname','message','phone','fax','company','website','myblogname','tempcode','temp_url','ajax');
    $attach = '';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $field)
    {
        if(!in_array($key,$already_used))
        {
            $attach.= $key.": ".$field."<br /> \n";
        }
    }
    $attach.= "<br /> \n";

    if(!checkmymail($the_email))
    {
        $errorC = true;
        $the_emailclass = "error";
    }else{
        $the_emailclass = "valid";
        }

    if($the_message == "")
    {
        $errorC = true;
        $the_messageclass = "error";
    }else{
        $the_messageclass = "valid";
        }

    if($errorC == false)
    {   
        $to      =  $the_myemail;
        $subject = "New Message from " . $the_blogname;
        $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'From:'. $the_email  . " \r\n";

        $message1 = nl2br($the_message);

        if(!empty($the_name))       $the_name       = "Name:    $the_name <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_company))    $the_company    = "Company: $the_company <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_phone))      $the_phone      = "Phone:   $the_phone <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_fax))        $the_fax        = "Fax:     $the_fax <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_website))    $the_website    = "Website: $the_website <br/>";

        $message = "
        You have a new message! <br/>
        $the_name
        $the_company
        $the_phone
        $the_website

        $attach <br />

        Message: $message1 <br />";



        if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)) $send = true; else $send = false;

        if(isset($_POST['ajax'])){

        if ($send)
        echo '<h3><img src="images/icon_check.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Your message has been sent!</h3><div class="confirm">


              </div>';
        else
        echo '<h3>Oops!</h3><div class="confirm">
                <p class="texterror">Due to an unknown error, your form was not submitted, please resubmit it or try later.</p>
              </div>'; 

        }
    }

}


function checkmymail($mailadresse){
$email_flag=preg_match("!^\w[\w|\.|\-]+@\w[\w|\.|\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]   {2,4}$!",$mailadresse);
return $email_flag;
}

?>
```

**For refrence i am using below ajax call**

```
 function tfuse_form1(){

var my_error;
var url = jQuery("input[name=temp_url]").attr('value');
jQuery(".ajax_form #send").bind("click", function(){

my_error = false;
jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form select").each(function(i)
{
            var surrounding_element = jQuery(this);
            var value               = jQuery(this).attr("value"); 
            var check_for           = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var required            = jQuery(this).hasClass("required"); 

            if(check_for == "email"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");
                if(!value.match(/^\w[\w|\.|\-]+@\w[\w|\.|\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)){
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid"); 
                }
            }

            if(check_for == "name" || check_for == "message"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");

                if(value == "" || value == 'Name (required)' || value == 'Type your message' ){ 
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid");
                }
            }

            if(required && check_for != "name" && check_for != "email" && check_for != "message"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");
                if(value == ""){                    
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid"); 
                }
            }


            if(jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form select").length  == i+1){
                    if(my_error == false){
                        jQuery(".ajax_form").slideUp(400);

                        var $datastring = "ajax=true";
                        jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form select").each(function(i)
                        {
                            var $name = jQuery(this).attr('name');  
                            var $value = encodeURIComponent(jQuery(this).attr('value'));
                            $datastring = $datastring + "&" + $name + "=" + $value;
                        });


                        jQuery(".ajax_form #send").fadeOut(100);    

                        jQuery.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "./sendmail.php",
                           data: $datastring,
                           success: function(response){
                               jQuery(".ajax_form").before("<div class='ajaxresponse'></div>");
                               jQuery(".ajaxresponse").html(response).slideDown(400); 
                               jQuery(".ajax_form #send").fadeIn(400);
                               jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form select").val("");
                            }
                        });
                    } 
                }
        });
        return false;
});
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure error_reporting is enabled, and check the error log on the live PHP site. You have not posted any PHP code, but common problems are things like an old PHP version, resulting in parse errors for newer syntax, or more commonly `<?` short open tags being disabled, rather than `<?php`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski phpcode is fine & working on the other servers, however let me edit my question & paste my php code.

Comment: posting your `phpInfo` link on this site is a really bad idea for security reasons. If it was me I would move the location of it

Comment: @charlietfl thanks alot i remove that

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski have added the php code too

Comment: I bet the mailto is failing:  `if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$header))`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski error_reporting is 22527

Comment: @James but its working on the other server here :(
http://www.virtualmob.co.uk/products/test_landing_pages/UrbanSpot/contact.html

Comment: @user202196 Have you matched PHP info settings in the both the servers. Pleas make sure that both are same as your code running smoothly in one of then

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary yes nice idea, i have checked the necessary things however let me check agian

Comment: @user202196 as you are keep repeating, that your code has worked on your dev-server I'd just like to tell you that two server setups are almost never identical. Also what does mean "Not working"? You haven't posted any error message nor an error description by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it runs on some servers but not others leads me to think it isn't the code that has a problem.  You reference the phpinfo page for the problem server but have you compared it to the phpinfo page from one of the working servers?  You could be running different versions of PHP.  Also check the php.ini files from the working and non working servers to verify all the correct extensions are loaded.

Comment: Cool now it is working, i asked server administrator to match the settings.